# Which were the 55 countries that voted against condemning Hamas at the UN?

Tags: united-nations, gaza, hamas, unga

The Times of Israel reports on the recent UNGA [resolution](https://www.timesofisrael.com/un-resolution-urging-immediate-gaza-ceasefire-passes-with-overwhelming-majority) calling for an immediate ceasefire in Gaza (which was adopted by 120-14-45):

> Canada sought to have an amendment added to the resolution to include a condemnation of Hamas and a majority of members backed the proposal, but it fell short of the two-thirds majority needed to be adopted. Eighty-eight countries voted for the amendment, 55 voted against and 33 abstained.
>
> Jordan’s ambassador to the UN called the amendment an effort to “whitewash” Israeli “atrocities” in Gaza.

There is a screenshot there of the countries that voted for the (unamended) resolution, but there is not one for the vote on the Canadian amendment. So, which countries (besides Jordan) voted against condemning Hamas?

There's UN voting data [on their site](https://digitallibrary.un.org/search?ln=en&as=1&cc=Voting+Data&m1=a&p1=Protection+of+civilians+and+upholding+legal+and+humanitarian+obligations&f1=&op1=a&m2=a&p2=&f2=&op2=a&m3=a&p3=&f3=&dt=&d1d=&d1m=&d1y=&d2d=&d2m=&d2y=&rm=wrd&action_search=Search&sf=&so=d&rg=50&c=Voting+Data&c=&of=hb&fti=0&fti=0) but it doesn't seem to include failed ammendments, unless I missed some query options.

Comment: Note that sponsors consult with all Member States during the drafting process and consensus on the wording is supposed to be reached. Thus the tabled version of a resolution should already be "the best version possible". Whether Canada was involved in this resolution's drafting is unclear. Major amendments to tabled resolutions usually require at least one more round of negotiations to work out a wording everyone can agree on.

Answer (score 16):

I managed to find it; they only seem to post these on Twitter. China and Russia were among those opposing that amendment. And the countries in their vicinity (Central Asia). Plus many Muslim countries and some African ones (incl. South Africa), as expected. Apologies for not transcribing the full list for now:

[image]

This wasn't technically part of my Q, but there's also the text of the amendment there, only as a photo for now.

[image]

The unamended resolution that did pass doesn't specifically name Hamas [at all] but condemns more generically "all acts of violence aimed at Palestinian and Israeli civilians, including all acts of terrorism and indiscriminate attacks, as well as all acts of provocation, incitement and destruction".

Comment: The unamended resolution also *"Calls for the immediate and unconditional release of all civilians who are being illegally held captive"*, though even this doesn't quite make the proposed amendment redundant since not all of the captives are civilians.

Comment: Interestingly the results almost mirror 2018 when a resolution failed 87-58-32 https://www.france24.com/en/20181207-usa-fails-bid-united-nations-condemnation-hamas-palestine-israel-nikki-haley

Answer (score 7):

In list format...

```
Algeria
Bahrain
Bangladesh
Belarus
Belize
Bolivia
Brunei Darussalam
Central African Republic
Chad
China
Comoros
Congo
Cuba
Democratic People's Republic of Korea
Djibouti
Egypt
Gambia
Guinea
Guyana
Indonesia
Iran (Islamic Republic of)
Iraq
Jordan
Kazakhstan
Kuwait
Kyrgyzstan
Lebanon
Libya
Malaysia
Maldives
Mali
Mauritania
Morocco
Namibia
Nicaragua
Niger
Oman
Pakistan
Qatar
Russian Federation
Saudi Arabia
Senegal
Somalia
South Africa
Sri Lanka
Sudan
Syrian Arab Republic
Tajikistan
Tunisia
Türkiye
Uganda
United Arab Emirates
United Republic of Tanzania
Yemen
Zimbabwe
```

Source:

> Canada-led amendment to the draft resolution on the Gaza crisis fails to pass at the UN General Assembly; it did not achieve two-thirds majority
>
> FAVOUR the amendment: 88
> AGAINST the amendment: 55
> ABSTENTIONS:  23
>
> Our LIVE COVERAGE:
> https://news.un.org/en/story/2023/

https://twitter.com/UN_News_Centre/status/1717991362010792164

[image: Screenshot showing the result of the countries who voted in favor and against Draft amendment A/ES-10/L.26]